# Protecting directories with htaccess by checking logged in user

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I've been trying to create a website that allows users to upload word documents.. Those documents would then be stored in a public directory of the website. The thing is, I don't want everyone to access the uploaded documents.. I would like to check if they are logged in first, and if they are "Authorized Users".. say if they have account level of 50 or higher, then they are allowed to open the directory..

Is there anyway I can do this through .htaccess?.. or is there a better solution?

I don't know if this is a dumb question, but do help me please. I would deeply appreciate any help I can get right now.

**Note:**

Sorry for not mentioning earlier, but I actually want to use google docs for viewing these documents in order to embed them in my website.

Comment: You will need to use PHP (probably with some rewrite rules) to authenticate and then set the correct headers and then read the file and output the file in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're taking the approach of putting the public documents directory somewhere underneath your web root directory. For a number of reasons (security, portability, maintainability), this is not the best approach to take.

Here's a quick-and-dirty approach (I'm assuming that you're already handling user authentication using a database or some other means to store credentials):

1. Place the documents directory somewhere outside your web root directory.
2. Create a function (or class) to read the list of files in the documents directory (look at `scandir()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
3. Create a page that will show the results of reading the documents directory. Each file should be a link to a page along with a URL parameter indicating the file. In this page, check the user's credentials before showing them the file list.
4. In the page that the file list page points to, check to make sure the requested file exists in the documents directory (don't forget to check again to make sure the user has the necessary credentials!), and then read that file and push it to the user. See `readfile()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), making special note in the example of setting the various header fields.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I was actually thinking of using Google docs to view the word documents since I wanted the files to be embedded in my website. Considering your solution, would it be possible for Google to view those documents outside the webroot?

Comment: I haven't worked extensively with the Google Docs API (now Google Drive API), but generally speaking you would need to store the documents on Google Drive and use their API (https://developers.google.com/drive/) to list the files on your site and then direct users to Google Docs to edit them. Given that Google already has that functionality built in (as well as sharing and permissions), it would probably be easier to just show users how to use that. I don't believe that you can have Google read the documents that are located locally on your server.

Comment: Viewing documents using Google is actually possible. If you are interested here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726288/need-to-view-ms-office-documents-in-a-php-web-based-document-management-system

Anyway, thank you for trying your best in answering my problem. If I may, I wanted the ask one last question. I have been lookin for alternatives.. I was able to disable direct download of documents.. even if they are stored inside the webroot. Problem is that Google is not able to view the docs anymore since they download it directly. Is there a way to view them in a similar way?

Comment: You may be in a catch 22 here. For the Google Docs viewer to be able to display your document, it has to have a publicly reachable URL. Having a publicly reachable URL means that the document isn't controlled by credentials (it doesn't appear that Google Docs can pass credentials). You could develop a solution that uses `readfile()` along with a one-time code generated by your application to give Google Docs a URL that would work only once. Doing so would require a bit more development on your part, but it's the only method that comes to mind.

Comment: At this point it really does appear to be the only solution. Alright then, a lot of thanks. You've been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to probably use a database (MySQL?) and PHP sessions to check if:

1. the user has logged in successfully (credentials in database)
2. the user has 'level 50' or higher `if($level >= 50)`
3. use sessions and session variables to create persistent authentication keys when users go between pages.
4. you should not need to use .htaccess files for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have actually thought of this solution already. The problem is that I wanted to use Google docs in order to view these word documents, and I think Google would require an actual file instead of a blob data to view files successfully. Correct me if I'm wrong though, I'm a bit new to these things.